# Rendering a custom table in Vuejs

Tags: vuejs3

I am trying to render a table based on JSON object that I get from an API. The simplified object looks like this:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "enabled": true,
  "headers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "header_name": "LastName",
      "colVal": { "id": 1, "value": "Hopper" }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "header_name": "FirstName",
      "colVal": { "id": 1, "value": "Grace" }
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want to be able to do from this JSON object is create a table like this:

| LastName | FirstName |
| --- | --- |
| Hopper | Grace |

Also, this table could have more data in `colVal`, in this case the JSON will look like this

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "enabled": true,
  "headers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "header_name": "LastName",
      "colVal": [
        { "id": 1, "value": "Hopper" },
        { "id": 3, "value": "Lovelace" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "header_name": "FirstName",
      "colVal": [
        { "id": 2, "value": "Grace" },
        { "id": 4, "value": "Ada" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And this would be rendered as follows:

| LastName | FirstName |
| --- | --- |
| Hopper | Grace |
| Lovelace | Ada |

So far I've managed to generalize it enough that I can get the table headers rendered properly but the col values are going to the correct columns, instead a new row is being created. Here is the code

```html
<table v-if="apiResponseData.custom_field_table[0].enabled_ind == true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th
        v-for="header in apiResponseData.custom_field_table[0].headers"
        :key="header.id"
      >
        {{ header.header_name }}
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="headerVal in apiResponseData.custom_field_table">
      <div v-for="col in headerVal.headers">
        <td style="width: 1%; border: 1px solid; text-align: center">
          {{ col.colVal[0].value }}
        </td>
      </div>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could wrangle the template to be able to use the data in its current form, I think you might be better served by running the data through a computed, which will make it much simpler. The thing that complicates the template is that the data array goes in the "horizontal" direction first and the "vertical" second, this makes constructing the loop more complicated. If you transpoze your data, the template will be much simpler.

script:

```js
const headers = computed(()=>{
  return hdrData?.headers.map(h => ({header:h.header_name, id:h.id}))
})

const rows = computed(()=>{
  let rowData = [];
  hdrData?.headers.forEach(h => {
    let key = h.header_name
    h.colVal.forEach((r, i) => {
      if(!rowData[i]) {rowData[i] = {id:i}}
      rowData[i][key] = r.value
    })
  })
  return rowData
})
```

template:

```html
<table v-if="headers">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th v-for="{header, id} in headers" :key="id">{{header}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="row in rows" :key={row.id}>
      <div v-for="{title, id} in headers">
        <td style="width: 1%; border: 1px solid; text-align: center">
          {{ row[header] }}
        </td>
      </div>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey Daniel, I think I understand what you mean. I'm a little unsure about where you're calling the `computed` functions in the script and I'm a little unsure about the syntax `hdrData?.headers`, is this essentially just selecting the correct child objects from the JSON?

Comment: computed can be called through composition or the options API, the example would be from composition. `hdrData?.headers` just prevents an error if `hdrData` is missing `headers`  that way `<table v-if="headers">` won't show if the data is not loaded, it's just an example, you may need to adjust to your existing script

Comment: Your solution worked for the most part, I just had to change it a tiny bit. Thanks for putting me on the right track and writing up the solution!